# Why does changing one array alters the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider this tiny bit of javascript code:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = a;

b[1] = 3;

a; // a === [1, 3, 3] wtf!?
```

Why does "a" change when I update "b[1]"? I've tested it in Firefox and Chrome. This doesn't happen to a simple number for example. Is this the expected behaviour?

```
var a = 1,
    b = a;

b = 3;

a; // a === 1 phew!
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because "a" and "b" reference **the same array**.  There aren't two of them; assigning the value of "a" to "b" assigns the *reference* to the array, **not** a  *copy* of the array.

When you assign *numbers*, you're dealing with primitive types. Even on a Number instance there's no method to update the value.

You can see the same "they're pointing to the same object" behavior with Date instances:

```
var d1 = new Date(), d2 = d1;
d1.setMonth(11); d1.setDate(25);
alert(d2.toString()); // alerts Christmas day
```

Answer (score 14):

It's the same array (since it's an object, it's the same reference), you need to create a copy to manipulate them separately using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) (which creates a new array with the elements at the first level copied over), like this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = a.slice();

b[1] = 3;

a; // a === [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You should explain why you're using slice... and also mention that the copy is only one level deep

Comment: @Juan - I provided a link directly to the some of the best documentation available for a full explanation, added a bit more here though.

Comment: thanks for the .slice() solution! This is going to be used a lot :)

Comment: I've always used Array.concat

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, if you want a copy of an array, one approach is to use the slice method:

```
var b = a.slice(0)
```

Comment: Actually it's brilliant addition!

Answer (score 1):

All Javascript objects are passed by reference - you would need to copy the entire object, not assign it.

For arrays this would be simple - just do something like:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a.slice(0);
```

where `slice(0)` returns the array from offset `0` to the end of the array.

[This link](http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165) has more info.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between **[Value types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type)** and **[Reference types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type)**.

Basicly Value types are stored on the computers "Stack" directly which means that you actualy have the "Value" and not what is called a Pointer/Reference.

A Reference Type on the other hand, does not hold the actual value of the object/variable but instead it points ( references ) to where you can find the value.

Thus when you say "My Reference Type B points to what Reference Type A points to", you actually have two variables pointing in the same direction and when you interact with either of them and change something, both will be pointing to the changed place, since the pointed to the same place from the begining.

In your other case you say "Hey, copy the value in variable A to variable B" and thus you have the values on seperate places which means that any change to either of them will not affect the other.

Comment: Just to correct your last point. The assignment is *not* different when the values are Numbers. The reason the second example is different is because the *change* (`b = 3`) is another assignment, where earlier it was making a mutable change to the original object

Comment: @Gareth, isn't that what I said? The assignment copys the value and therefore when you change it, it doesn't effect "a".

Comment: Sorry yes, I got the impression in my first reading that you were distinguishing between primitives and other objects as rvalues. My bad

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays are references to actual place where they are stored.

Comment: Variables are references to the places where their objects are stored, is more the issue here

Comment: @Gareth That's what I said... Array is a variable, the way you think of arrays when you use them is not in terms of how they are stored, but in terms of how they are used (as variables, that is).

Answer (score 0):

the statement `x = y` is the only special one here, it means "point the variable `x` at the object `y`.

Pretty much every other operation is an operation which changes the object referred to by `x`

```
b = a;
b[1] = 3;
```

So, your first statement points the variable `b` at the array also referred to as `a`

Your second statement alters the array pointed to by `b` (and also by `a`)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an array does not create a new array, it's just a reference to the same array. Numbers and booleans are copied when assigned to a new variable.