# Complex object of Service changes from component after returning from service function in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services, angular-components

Elaborating my question more,

I have a service called `hero.service.ts` which is being used in a component called `hero.component.ts`. `hero.service.ts` contains a variable `heros` which is an `array` and contains many items.

I am getting values of `heros` from `hero.service.ts` by a function called `getHeroes()` which returns the variable as `return this.heros;` and getting the values on component by `this.heros = this.heroService.getHeroes()`.

In my component, listing of heros there in a table. **When i delete rows from table it actually deletes from the variable `heros` of `hero.service.ts` too.**

- why is this happening ?
- Why it is returning the variable reference instead just a values.

FYI, i achieved it by returning `heros` with `...` spreading operator like `return [...this.heros];`. But why service passing reference of variable. please help guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does changing one array alters the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220611/why-does-changing-one-array-alters-the-other)

Comment: Hey @sloth. This is seen in angular 1 and javascript. but considering angular 5 which is typescript, how this is happening? what is actually behind this. I just want to know.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)? It's hard to believe :P

Comment: Workaround: `const refArray  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalArray))`

Comment: @YashMajithiya The problem is the same: you pass a reference to an array from one place to another, but the reference is still pointing to *the same* array.

Comment: @sloth, he mentioned that he did `return [...this.heros];`. That should have created a new array for sure.

Comment: @SiddAjmera `return [...this.heros];` solves the issue. problem is with `return this.heros;`. i just wanted to know why service is passing variable reference here and what is the solution for this.

Comment: @OmerShukar this is a case and can be done by making just a new variable. i want to know why returning reference...?

Comment: the x = y operation is a referencing operation, you are actually saying - when I say x, I mean y. If you would like to have an undependant variable, you have to either `.map` the original one, or set it as an `Observable` in `hero.service.ts` and `subscribe` to the stream from within the `hero.component.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, Complex data types like Arrays and Objects, are passed by reference and NOT by value.

When you returned `this.heros;` from your service, your component didn't get the heroes Array. It got the reference to the heroes array in memory.

So essentially at this point, both the heroes properties in your Component as well as in the Service, were pointing to the same Array in memory.

To fix this when you did `return [...this.heros];`, this time it spread the elements of the heroes array into a new array that was created on the fly, and then returned the reference to that newly created array to your component.

That time, the component heroes were pointing to a different array in memory. Hence when you do that, you get the expected outcome where the hero is deleted from the Component Array but not from the service array.

Here's a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tour-of-heroes-eg-demo?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.